# Is NuxtJS only for NodeJS frameworks?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to NuxtJs and try to use it in my next vuejs project. But the problem is that the backend is ktor a kotlin framework. So i cannot find a single example or direction how to deploy my dist ( server, client folders in it ) into hosting. All the examples available on the internet i came across with is done with Node.JS frameworks. So is it only for Node.JS based frameworks, if no how can I deploy my project in Nuxt.js?

Comment: Nuxt.js **is** a Node.js-based framework. It merges backend and frontend into a single code base.

Comment: You could build your Nuxt project separately into a static site (server rendered once) with Node.js and then serve the static files anywhere.

Comment: @str it dont merge backend. nuxt is a frontend solution.

Comment: @str universal doesnt mean its backend. Its still frontend. Backend is a totally different thing

Answer (score 1):

Nuxt is totally agnostic to backend framework. It can work with any backend framework you want.

As for deployment, its depends on the nuxt mode you want to use. If you want to use SSR mode e.g. have a running node server. Then for production you can for example run both nuxt and your backend behind nginx proxy. https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy/